# angular and ngrx : can you dispatch an action in a loop?

Tags: loops, ngrx

I have defined an effect that calls an api that deletes a file with a certain uuid in the server:

```
@Effect()
  deleteFileImport$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.runs.DELETE_FILE_IMPORT),
    map((action: any) => action.payload),
    switchMap((fileImport: FileImport) =>
      this.rest.del(fileImportUrl + fileImport.uuid + '/').pipe(
        map((response: FileImport) => new actions.runs.DeleteFileImportSuccess(response)),
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log('DELETE_FILE_IMPORT error', err);
          return observableOf(new NotificationAction({
              title: 'File Import Delete Failed',
              body: 'Failed to delete file import: ' + fileImport.filename
            })
          );
        })
      )
    )
  );
```

if I call this effect in a loop:

```
importFilesToDelete.forEach(file => {
      this.store.dispatch(new actions.runs.DeleteFileImport(file));
    });
```

only the first one get deleted. If I track the calls to dispatch I can see that all file are processed with the correct parameters passed but only the first action is executed. Am I missing something in the way ngrx works? Can you dispatch actions in a loop?

Comment: Try using `concatMap` or `mergeMap` rather than `switchMap` in the effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator which will cancel pending requests.
Use the [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) if the order is important or the [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) operator if the order of executing is not important.